# ENVI shows colors of different RGB code the same in a bitmap image wrongly?

Tags: remote-sensing, envi, color, matlab, rgb

As you see in this picture which I've captured in MATLAB, there are two colors.

- Red with the RGB code (255,0,0)
- Brown with the RGB code (138,139,1)

[image]

I've tried to show the same picture in ENVI, but as you see the RGB codes (255,0,0) and (138,139,0) both appear as red in ENVI.

[image]

Does anyone know why this occurs and what should I do to fix it?